# .sh working on terminal but not on cronjob

Tags: mac-osx, cron, archive

I have created a shell file to extract an archive from .7z. The shell works fine in the terminal but in the cronjob I get an error.

The command is:

```
7z x /path/to/file.7z -aoa
```

The error I receive is:

```
/path/to/script.sh: line 2: 7z: command not found
```

I am using the full path to the .7z file and I checked my permissions so I am breaking my head to find out what I am doing wrong.

I changed my script to

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/7z x /path/to/file.7z -aoa
```

I now get

```
/bin/sh: /path/to/script.sh: Permission denied
```

I have checked the script, file and 7z files and all permissions are set to read/write

OK.. So I fixed the permission issue by using chmod +x on the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the path to the `.7z` file, it's the path to the executable `7z`

I'm guessing that `7z` came from something like HomeBrew, so is not on the default path and your user has a `.profile` or similar entry that adds directories to the PATH env var.

Use `which 7z` command to find the full path to `7z` and edit the script to use that path.

Comment: Yes, this is HomeBrew. I found the location of the command at /usr/local/bin
but I am not sure what I need to do...

Comment: Edit the script to include the full path to the command e.g. `/usr/local/bin/7z x /path/to/file.7z`

Comment: The command you recommended works fine on terminal but in the cron I get the same error "7z: command not found"

Comment: [Edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1034029/edit) the question to show your FULL script including the modifications and the full new error.

Answer (score 0):

Put the full path on the `7z` command. The problem you're having is that cronjob doesn't have the same PATH as your shell.
You can find the full path of the `7z` with `command -v 7z` command.